# CSS4 solution for transition 0 to auto?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I was going through the CSS4 articles but I was not able to find it.

In CSS3, when transitions were introduced, one of the popular issues was transitioning height from 0 to auto without having to use JavaScript.

We did have the `max-height` solution, but that will only have an accurate `transition-duration` for that height. If `auto` of that element is say double the max-height then we will see a noticeable jump.

Does CSS4 provide a solution for this 0 to auto issue? Especially for height/width?

Comment: Considering transitions are level 1 and *still* not even a Candidate Recommendation, by the time we make it to level 4 you'll probably have retired. But in all seriousness, there is no "CSS4" - even if we assume the current Transitions spec is stable, the next level is 2. Every article you read that talks about "CSS4" doesn't understand how the CSS3 specs really work. That's probably part of why you haven't been able to find anything. (Not that css-transitions-2 offers any solution to this problem either...)

Comment: In the only field where we are "progressing" is in display formats. In the CSStricks article linked by patelarpan, see the last method using flexbox. This "new" technique allows you to change the way we try to solve the problem. But doesn't seem that we will be able to transition height to auto in any near future.

Comment: @vals: Yeah, it's a fundamental limitation of block layout in CSS. Only way to solve it would be to redefine the auto value. Yeah... not gonna happen.

Comment: Haha thanks @BoltClock for your funny but also very informative first comment.

Comment: Thanks very much @vals for commenting out patelarpan's article, I will keep that in mind while reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is great article about this on css trick https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much @patelarpan, I will read this now. I was able to solve my issues by using javascript, was just hoping to peak at the future, where this was hopefully solved. In combination with your article, and BoltClock's and val's comments I'll accept this solution. It seems CSS4 is not real haha.